# tinyMCE Image Displaying Correctly, but not Updating src

Tags: javascript, tinymce, image

I've run into a strange problem with the tinyMCE and images.  I'm trying to update an image that's already been added to the tinyMCE.  For example, let's say I have the following image

```
<img src="image1.png" title="title1" alt="alt1" class="class1" />
```

I run the following script:

```
imageNode.setAttribute('src', 'image2.png');
imageNode.setAttribute('title', 'title2');
imageNode.setAttribute('alt', 'alt2');
imageNode.setAttribute('class', 'class2');
```

And the result is:

```
<img src="image1.png" title="title2" alt="alt2" class="class2" />
```

Notice that I'm still getting image1, not image2, yet everything else is updating fine.  Further, the new image (image2) displays in the tinyMCE, not the old image.  Still, when I click the HTML button on the tinyMCE, it shows that the `src` has not updated correctly.

When I look at the source code, I see:

```
<img src="image2.png" data-mce-src="image1.png" title="title2" alt="alt2" class="class2" />
```

Notice here that the `src` is actually correct, but there is an additional attribute `data-mce-src`.  When I try to update my content.  `That data-mce-src` seems to be used as the `src` of my image.

Is there another way that I should be setting the `src` of my image besides `setAttribute`?

**UPDATE:**

I'm thinking it has something to do with this http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:convert_urls

However, I like that it uses relative URLs and I'd like to keep that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I added `imageNode.setAttribute('data-mce-src', 'image2.png');` and that did the trick.  Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it adding in tinymce.init :

```
relative_urls : false,
content_css : ""
convert_urls : false,
```